# How to prevent access for users to another views using stateprovider

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have some issues while i'm trying to prevent users from accessing my other views.
This is my module:

```
angular.module('Project', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.bootstrap.tpls', 'cgBusy', 'ui.router', 'templates', 'pascalprecht.translate'])
    .value('cgBusyDefaults', {
        message: 'Please wait ...',
        backdrop: true,
        delay: 300
    })
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state('LoginForCustomerInfo', {
            url: '/LoginForCustomerInfo',
            templateUrl: 'app/WebShop/ProjectFeatures/LoginForCustomerInfo/templates/customerInfo.html',
            controller: 'customerInfoCtrl'
        });
        $stateProvider.state('UserInformation', {
            url: '/UserInformation',
            controller: 'UserInformationCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'app/WebShop/ProjectFeatures/UserInformation/templates/userInformation.html'
    }).state('UserInformation.updateAddress', {
            url: '/UpdateAddress',
            templateUrl: 'app/WebShop/ProjectFeatures/UpdateAddressInformation/templates/addressUpdate.html',
            controller: 'AddressController'
        }).state('UserInformation.updateContactInfo', {
            url: '/UpdateCI',
            templateUrl: 'app/WebShop/ProjectFeatures/UpdateContactInformation/templates/contactUpdate.html',
            controller: 'ContactController'
        }).state('UserInformation.viewVoucherHistory', {
            url: '/ViewVoucherHistory',
            templateUrl: 'app/WebShop/ProjectFeatures/ViewVoucherHistory/templates/viewVoucherHistory.html',
            controller: 'voucherhistoryCtrl'
        }).state('UserInformation.shoppingCart', {
            url: '/ShoppingCart',
            templateUrl: 'app/WebShop/ProjectFeatures/ShoppingCart/templates/shoppingCart.html',
            controller: 'ShoppingCartController'
        });
```

If i write in the search bar this http://localhost/project/#/UserInformation/UpdateCI it will go to that page and I don't want that, first I want the users to login and after they will have access to UpdateAddress, UpdateContactInformation and so on.
Help me with some tips. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent an user to access pages without getting signed in, you should use the `run` function and check if client is logged. If he is not, check if he is on another page than the login page and redirect if he is.

I recommand you to use [ngCookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore) to do it, because AngularJS alone cannot keep data if user refresh its page. **I hope you don't need to have this application securized because it is not with this way.**

I'd write it like this :

```
app.run(['$route', '$location', 'loginService', function($route, $location, loginService) {
    if ($route.current !== '/LoginForCustomerInfo' && !loginService.isLogged()) { // Redirect if the user is not logged and not the login page
        $location.path('/LoginForCustomerInfo');
    }
}]);
```

And your loginService'd look like :

```
app.factory('loginService', ['$cookieStore', function ($cookieStore) {
    return {
        isLogged: function () { // Check if user is logged
            return $cookieStore.get('id') !== null;
        },
        loggin: function (id) { // Store its id in the browser's cookies
            $cookieStore.put('id', id);
        }
    }
}]);
```

And your customerInfoCtrl controller look like :

```
app.controller('customerInfoCtrl', '$location', ['loginService', function($loginService, $location) {

    if (loginService.isLogged()) { // If user is yet logged, redirect
        $location.path('/UserInformation');
    }

    $scope.submit(function() { // When submit the login form, put the id in the browser's cookies
        loginService.login($scope.id);
        $location.path('/UserInformation');
    });
}]);
```

Do not forget to include `angular-cookie.js` and inject it in modules like this :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/XXXX/angular-cookies.js"></script>

angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies']);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but my login is just a number which everyone get if is a customer of a magazine.

Comment: And how do you know if the customer is a part of a magazine ?

Comment: Ok, on the login page, you just have a to put a number, then when you access the other pages, you use that number ? And you want to prevent access to other pages than login if user doesn't have an id ?

Comment: Yes, this is what i want.